# $.ajax values not returning correctly

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get returned values from database from a PHP array to a JavaScript array.
So far what I've done is returning the values as a string and I want each value as an array
index.

This is my jQuery AJAX Call:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "Profile_Control.php",
          data:"ajaxRequest=yes&id="+document.getElementById("compid").value,
          success:function(data)
          {       
              document.getElementById("asd").innerHTML=data;
          }
        });
```

and this is my PHP script so far, which is returning the values like a string and I want each value in the array index.

```
   $branches=Profile_Model::getCompanyBranches($_GET['id']);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($branches))
    {
        echo $row[3];
    }
```

Now I am only echoing column 3 of the values returned from database and the output is like this:

```
        67.030867.020467.031167.020667.0357
```

and the result I want should be like this.

```
   arr[0]=67.0308
   arr[1]=67.0204
   arr[2]=67.0311
   arr[3]=67.0206
   arr[4]=67.0357
```

I also tried encoding the data in JSON by using `json_encode($row[3]);` but it returns me the following result.

```
  "67.0308""67.0204""67.0311""67.0206""67.0357"
```

Comment: Instead of passing a string to `data`, you should use an object: `data: {ajaxRequest: 'yes', id: blah}`. Otherwise *you* have to take care about properly encoding the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array with the elements you eventually want in your JS array and then `json_encode` that array:

```
$rows = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($branches)) {
    $rows[] = $row[3];
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

However, `data` will be an array in your success callback so you cannot simply assign it to the `innerHTML` property of an element. But since that seems to be debug output simply replace it with `console.log(data);`.

Comment: thnx for the reply it worked but can you tell me how to send `$row[4]` also and how to access them from javascript because I want both the columns.

Comment: This depends on the structure. If you want a nested array, use `$rows[] = array($row[3], $row[4])`. However, consider creating an associative array with meaningful keys: `$rows[] = array('whatever' => $row[3], 'whateverelse' => $row[4])`. If your column names fit, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_object` and simply use `$rows[]= $row;` and you will get exactly what you want. Note that your JSON object will then contain all columns you fetched from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array with each element being `$row[3]`, send the new array via `json_encode`.

Right now you're just json_encoding each `$row[3]` individually.